# SQL Workbench- Generational table reading

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL, I have a bunch of tables test1 test2 test3----test100. Those tables are created on a daily basis and have same columns/format. I want to create a table that should have 1 month past data, in other words i have to combine test1-test30 into one single table. I can only thinks of the below code but i am looking for something efficient and easy to do like using loops or while conditions..or some other way

```
create table final as
select * from test1;
insert into final from test2
insert into final from test3
.
.
insert into final from test30..
```

Can you suggest me a simpler way to do this instead of using 30 insert statements

Comment: I think you should learn about partitioning.  There is no reason to store so many different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

Copy all columns from one table to another table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Copy only some columns from one table into another table:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Another solution is to dump the data from all your database if it has the same tables then insert it into .csv or txt file and import it into your final table.

```
Mysql -u [username] -p [database_name] < /path/to/file.[extention]
```